# Calling Release on COM object never appears to return

Tags: c++, windows, com

I'm debugging an intermittent issue on a customer site. I've got it down to the point that it appears that a call to `Release()` on a COM object is not returning.

The first log is printing but I never see the second log. I can only assume that the call to `Release()` never returned for some reason (or could it be the `CoInitializeEx()`).

I have no idea what to look for next, any help/clues would be greatly appreciated.

```
Logger::getLogger()->logTrace("AudioCapturer::_shutdown. _pEndpointAudioClient_COM Released. (%s)", _deviceName.c_str());
releaseComObject(_pAudioCaptureClient_COM);
Logger::getLogger()->logTrace("AudioCapturer::_shutdown (%s) succeeded", _deviceName.c_str());
```

Here is the supporting code:

```
IAudioCaptureClient *_pAudioCaptureClient_COM;

// Class that Initializes COM on creation and Unitializes on destruction
AutoCOM::AutoCOM() { CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); }
AutoCOM::~AutoCOM() { CoUninitialize(); }


#define AUTO_COM_SUPPORT AutoCOM _autoCOM

// Safe releasing of COM objects. Zeros the pointer
// to the COM object. Safe to use with NULL
// pointers.
template <class T> void releaseComObject(T*& pT) {
     if (pT) {
           AUTO_COM_SUPPORT;
           (pT)->Release();
           pT = NULL;
     }
}
```

Comment: The MSDN docs have a very specific warning about IAudioCaptureClient::Release().  Quote: "When releasing an IAudioCaptureClient interface instance, the client must call the Release method of the instance from the same thread as the call to IAudioClient::GetService that created the object."  Violating such a requirement is likely to cause deadlock.

Comment: If the `CoInitializeEx` call fails you're *still* doing `CoUnitialize`, which is wrong.

Comment: `#define AUTO_COM_SUPPORT AutoCOM` wow you do not want to do that. `releaseComObject` should know COM is already initialized or where does `pT` come from? Take out `AUTO_COM_SUPPORT` and burn it.

Comment: @HansPassant, Thank You. Looks like `Release()` is being called from a different thread. I'll fix it up and see if that helps.

Comment: @Ben, thanks, i'll get rid of that code.

Comment: Also make sure to fix the `AutoCOM` implementation. A quick fix would be to have the c'tor throw on failure (e.g. by using `_com_util::CheckError(CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED));` (declared in *comutil.h*). If you don't fix this, you may accidentally uninitialize COM on a thread prematurely. You also need to check, if the MT apartment is the correct apartment for your COM objects.

Comment: Really that AutoCom macro needs to die in a fire.

Comment: @IInspectable: I don't think this is the **real code**, since using (only) a type name as a statement won't compile. I voted to close as lacking example, first thing of all. But I think it indicates, as mentioned, that not only the likely purpose of re-initializing COM for multithreading (not possible AFAIK), but also the implementation, is deeply flawed.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That's correct. Once initialized into an STA or the MTA, a thread cannot move into another apartment. Any attempt to do so will fail with `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE`. As you noted, though, the d'tor would still run in case the initialization failed, which eventually leads to COM being uninitialized prematurely on a thread.

Answer (score 0):

Never found a duplication scenario for the issue. But the problem was averted with the user of smart pointers, which was mentioned by @Cheersandhth.-Alf. Thanks for the feedback.

Basically used the following macro to define smart pointers, and removed all references to `Release()`

`_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IMyInterface, __uuidof(IMyInterface));`